# C3JS load function and point value

Tags: javascript, php, c3.js

I am using the following function from c3js:

```
        chart.load({
          point: {
            r: function (d) {
              return 3;
            }
          },
          bindto: "#chatterplot_elastic",
          x: 'x',
          xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
          columns: [
            getPassantenTotaalOnDate(res),
            getPassantenDatesOnDate(res),
            AvHensbergenOnDate(res),
            GemeentehuisOnDate(res),
            CoornhertpadOnDate(res),
            DuivenweideOnDate(res),
            TricotageOnDate(res)
          ],
        });
```

As you can see i am using the chart.load function. This is all working fine except the point values wont't be updated to the value 3.

I think the .load function doesn't reconize the point setting that i am trying to change.

**My question : How do i make sure i can change the point value on the .load of c3js?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple reason for this: the load function is expecting some type of `config.data`.

You *want* to change `config.point` *but you try* to change `config.data.point` instead (which does not exist).

To get the desired behaviour you can add following line when you call the `load` function: `chart.internal.config.point_r = 3;`